# Docker container on VM not writing to ZFS dataset

Tags: kvm, docker, qemu, zfs, rtorrent

My setup is the following:

Physical host with QEMU/KVM -> VM with Docker -> rtorrent Docker container

I have a ZFS pool called "main" with a dataset called "data". The "data" dataset is mounted on the VM via the virtio kernel module as suggested via [this link](http://rabexc.org/posts/p9-setup-in-libvirt). From here, my rtorrent Docker container has its download volume mapped to the mounted dataset on the VM:

```
$ docker run -dt --name rtorrent-rutorrent --network=host -p 8080:80 -p 49160:49160/udp -p 49161:49161 -v /data/rtorrent:/downloads -e "NOIPV6=1" diameter/rtorrent-rutorrent:latest
```

Here's where I'm confused: when I'm attached to the container, I can write to the dataset via touch, wget without issues. When I add a torrent to rtorrent however, nothing writes. It sits on "downloading" with no download speed. As soon as I change the container volume to point to the Docker VM local disk, everything works without issues.

I've done a couple of straces on the rtorrent process ([link here](https://pastebin.com/FnXdAGeH)) but there's not a whole lot that stands out to me here. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: what are the owner, group, and permissions of `/data/rtorrent`?   What uid and gid does the rtorrent client in the container run as?  does that uid and/or gid have write access to that directory?  (if not, it should).  BTW, in case you haven't already done so, your torrent download dataset (`main/data/rtorrent` - which should be a separate dataset, not just a subdir of `main/data`) should have **16K** recordsize.

Comment: Owner and group are both "docker", folder is set to 777. UID and GID is 1000 via passthrough.

Comment: ok, so not perms then.  what happens if you set up rtorrent to download to the VM's disk and then mv it to the main/data/rtorrent dataset? (i'm assuming rtorrent can auto-move a download after it has completed).  test with a tiny torrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved via the following: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212014/245005

In short, a flag needed to be added to the mount options for this to work - "cache=mmap". Now works without issue.